# What is this beetle looking fly creature?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found this fly in my back garden that looks like a beetle with wings and it hovers.

> [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR8XA.png)
>
> [image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfwV3.png)

What is it?

Comment: @Remi.b I did add what environment I found it and where in the world I found it

Comment: Did you know that all beetles do have wings, and many of them do fly? I think it's going to be hard to identify based just on that picture, since it is quite blurry, but who knows, there are some masters here. It's almost certainly a beetle of some kind, though.

Comment: I got a clear video, shame you can't post videos.

Comment: It's slightly frowned upon because StackExchange likes to have everything contained on this site where possible to preserve the content of both questions and answers, but in this case I think it would be fine to link to a youtube video, or some other video service or video-to-gif host. Just if you do so, please don't remove it after you get an answer. If someone is able to answer your question they can put a high quality image in their answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is of course it is difficult to tell exactly from the quality of the image, but with mandibles of that size relative to the body (approx. 20-25% of total length) it is very likely to be a male Stag Beetle *Lucanus cervus*, the mandibles will grow much larger. The antenna sticking out from the side of the head just in front of the eye matches your photo (note: in the image below it looks like two on each side, but it is just the shadow in the photo)

[image]

Picture from Wikimedia commons https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lucanus_cervus_1922.png

They can be found flying at dusk, and are found in the SE of England from late May to August.

If you are looking for a good insect ID book, I can recommend "A comprehensive guide to Insects of Britain & Ireland" by Paul D. Brock, published in 2014